# controlling excel cells and writing it to other cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel sheet like at below. I want to find some strings in my excel's third cell. The string is **180 days**. When the cell value includes **180 days**, I want write previous cells value in next to empty cells like in below picture. I want to write process plan in first cell, operation title in second cell. I wrote this codes but it's not working like what I want.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim excelRange As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim k As Long
    'Dim txt As String
    excelRange = ActiveSheet.Cells(1048576, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    k = 2
    For a = 2 To excelRange
        txt = Cells(a, 3)
        k = a
        If InStr(1, txt, "180 days") > 0 Then
            For i = a To 2 Step -1
                txt1 = Cells(i, 3)
                If InStr(1, txt1, "Oper Title") > 0 Then
                    Cells(a, 2) = Cells((k + 1), 3)
                ElseIf InStr(1, txt1, "Process") > 0 Then
                    Cells(a, 1) = Cells(k, 3)
                Else:
                    k = k - 1
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    Next a
End Sub
```

[image: I want to do something like this]

Comment: if you have specific number of rows (blocks) for each process then you dont need vba. nested function if with search is enough... But its not clear from your image.

Comment: Cleaning up your code will help you eliminate confusion. First, declare all your variables. Second, write `txt = Cell(a, 3)` if you mean the cell (and txt is a range) and `Cell(a, 3).Value` if you mean the value (and txt is a string). Then give meaningful names to your variables. It seems `a`, `i` and `k` all are rows. Why haven't you used `R` for any of them? In fact, you should have only one row to deal with which is `a`. If `k` or `i` are different rows you would be over-writing existing information. You mention "empty cells" in your task description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub test()

Dim excelRange  As Range
Dim criteriRange As Range
Dim evaluateRange As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim i As Long

Set excelRange = Range("C1:C" & Cells(1048576, 3).End(xlUp).Row)

For Each cell In excelRange
    If UCase(cell.Text) Like "*180 DAY*" Then
        If criteriRange Is Nothing Then
            Set criteriRange = cell
        Else
            Set criteriRange = Union(criteriRange, cell)
        End If
    End If
Next

If Not criteriRange Is Nothing Then
    For Each c In criteriRange
        For i = c.Row To 1 Step -1
            If UCase(Cells(i, 3)) Like "*PROCESS PLAN*" Then
            c.Offset(0, -2) = Cells(i, 3)
            Exit For
            End If
        Next
        For i = c.Row To 1 Step -1
            If UCase(Cells(i, 3)) Like "*OPER TITLE*" Then
            c.Offset(0, -1) = Cells(i + 1, 3)
            Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next
End If


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping through a range, your macro will run much faster if you use the `Range.Find` method.

In your code, you did not check to ensure that all of your **sets** of `Process | Title | 180 Days` are complete.  I added that to the code below, by making sure that the `Process` and `Title` rows were found after the previous `180 day` row (or before the `180 day` row for the first instance).

In your code, you did not check to see if the cells where you want to output this information are, in fact, **empty**.  If you really want to do that, you can easily modify this code to check these cells before writing to them.

Hopefully, through the comments and the use of meaningful variable names, you will be able to understand what is going on. But you might want to also read through VBA Help for the `Range.Find` method.

In general, we search down to find the `180 day` row, then search up from there to find the associated `Process` and `Title` rows.

If a preceding `Process` or `Title` row should be before the preceding `180 day` row, then we have an incomplete set, output the error message, and terminate the procedure.

If necessary, you could develop procedures to deal with incomplete data sets.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Info()
    Dim searchRng As Range, C As Range, cProcessPlan As Range, cOperTitle As Range
    Dim firstAddress As String 'to check when we are done
    Dim lastAddress As String 'to check for incomplete data sets

'Where are we looking?
Set searchRng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(3)

With searchRng
    Set C = .Find(what:="180 Days", after:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, _
                lookat:=xlPart, searchorder:=xlByRows, _
                searchdirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
        If Not C Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = C.Address
            lastAddress = C.Address
            Set cOperTitle = .Find(what:="Oper Title", after:=C, searchdirection:=xlPrevious)
            Set cProcessPlan = .Find(what:="Process Plan", after:=C, searchdirection:=xlPrevious)

            If Not cOperTitle Is Nothing Or Not cProcessPlan Is Nothing Then

                'check for full set
                If cOperTitle.Row > Range(lastAddress).Row Or cProcessPlan.Row > Range(lastAddress).Row Then
                    MsgBox "Incomplete Data Set" & vbLf & "Before: " & C.Address
                    Exit Sub
                End If

                C.Offset(0, -1) = cOperTitle.Offset(1, 0)
                C.Offset(0, -2) = cProcessPlan
            Else
                MsgBox "Title or Process Plan not found"
                Exit Sub
            End If

            Do
                Set C = .Find(what:="180 Days", after:=C, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    lookat:=xlPart, searchorder:=xlByRows, _
                    searchdirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

                If C.Address = firstAddress Then Exit Do

                Set cOperTitle = .Find(what:="Oper Title", after:=C, searchdirection:=xlPrevious)
                Set cProcessPlan = .Find(what:="Process Plan", after:=C, searchdirection:=xlPrevious)

                'check for a full set
                If cOperTitle.Row < Range(lastAddress).Row Or cProcessPlan.Row < Range(lastAddress).Row Then
                    MsgBox "Incomplete Data Set" & vbLf & "Between: " & lastAddress & " and " & C.Address
                    Exit Sub
                End If

                C.Offset(0, -1) = cOperTitle.Offset(1, 0)
                C.Offset(0, -2) = cProcessPlan


                lastAddress = C.Address
            Loop
        End If
End With
'next stuff

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using a variant array is fast.

```
Sub test()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngDB As Range
    Dim vDB As Variant
    Dim vRow(), vTitle(), vProcess()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, m As Long

    Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    With Ws
        Set rngDB = .Range("a1", .Range("c" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With

    vDB = rngDB

    For i = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        If InStr(vDB(i, 3), "180 days") Then
            j = j + 1
            ReDim Preserve vRow(1 To j)
            vRow(j) = i
        ElseIf InStr(vDB(i, 3), "Oper Title") Then
            k = k + 1
            ReDim Preserve vTitle(1 To k)
            vTitle(k) = vDB(i + 1, 3)
        ElseIf InStr(vDB(i, 3), "Process") Then
            m = m + 1
            ReDim Preserve vProcess(1 To m)
            vProcess(m) = vDB(i, 3)
        End If
    Next i
    For i = 1 To j
        vDB(vRow(i), 1) = vProcess(i)
        vDB(vRow(i), 2) = vTitle(i)
    Next i
    rngDB = vDB

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm getting **Application-defined or object-defined error** at **rngDB=vDB**